# Documentation for Android's standard style

Tags: android

Currently, I know there are several official Android styles.

- @android:style/Theme.Black
- @android:style/Theme.Light
- @android:style/Theme.Translucent

But I can hardly find any **official** documentation regarding the above styles. Does anyone know where I can look for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that they basically know that it's poorly documented, and recommend just browsing the source. From [Using Platform Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles):

> The Android platform provides a large collection of styles and themes
>   that you can use in your applications. You can find a reference of all
>   available styles in the [`R.style`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) class. To use the styles listed
>   here, replace all underscores in the style name with a period. For
>   example, you can apply the `Theme_NoTitleBar` theme with
>   `"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.
>
> The `R.style` reference, however, is not well documented and does not
>   thoroughly describe the styles, so viewing the actual source code for
>   these styles and themes will give you a better understanding of what
>   style properties each one provides. For a better reference to the
>   Android styles and themes, see the following source code:
>
> - [Android Styles (styles.xml)](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD)
> - [Android Themes (themes.xml)](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=6b3d7407d1c895a3c297e60d5beac98e2d34c271;hb=HEAD)
>
> These files will help you learn through example. For instance, in the
>   Android themes source code, you'll find a declaration for `<style
>   name="Theme.Dialog">`. In this definition, you'll see all of the
>   properties that are used to style dialogs that are used by the Android
>   framework.